# Turn of kernel logging to serial port but keep logging to oops ramlog

Tags: linux-kernel, console, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, syslog

I'm working with a system that have one external serial port, this has been (and still is used in other configurations using the same kernel) for printing the kernel log (and application log). But now the serial port has to be used to communicate with an external device.

I found a way to make getty boot depending on a file on a configuration file on the file system, but I have not been able to turn of the logging to the serial port and still keep the logging to the crash dump, the crash dumps utilize the oops logs stored "persistent" in RAM (i.e. they survive a soft reboot) and stores them at the next boot.

If I use,
`dmesg --console-off`
it will turn of both the logging to the serial port as well as the logging to the oops logs.

Currently I have `bootargs = "console=ttyPS0,115200 loglevel=7 ...` the bootargs are shared with another product that, if possible, wishes to keep the log printouts over the serial interface.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can prevent the logs to be printed on the serial interface but still be logged in the oops logs? I have the possibility to edit all from the kernel, kernel module/drivers and user space apps.

Comment: If you want to use the serial port for communciation with an external device, why do you tell the kernel to use it for output at all?

Comment: @Toto, there are legacy reason for the bootargs; we are using the same kernel and dts file for more then one product (and would prefer to continue using the same kernel and config). I guess another option would be if I for the other products could add the console after mounting the rootfs.

Comment: As I understood the question the kernel output to the serial port is interfering with the goal to use the serial port for communicating with periphery. So I wanted to suggest to remove console from the bootargs. Kernel, dts could be the same.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, the problem is that I'm running the same kernel for two different applications. One of them wants to keep the output on the serial port and the new application want to use the same port for the peripheral device, in the best of worlds I want to use the same kernel and select at runtime to if the serial port shall be used for output or not..

Comment: If you remove `console=ttySx...` (where `ttySx` is the port for serial console) it won't prevent you to use `getty` on it. So, you will have an ability to grab the port in your second application when needed. Of course two apps won't work simultaneously. For that you need hardware with two or more physical serial interfaces.